# Managing Objects within Activities to avoid using Null

Tags: android, kotlin

One of the benefits of using Kotlin is its Null safety. However when I have been programming Android Apps using it, I have found myself needing to use null. When declaring my UI elements such as TextViews and Buttons etc. I need to create private variables that are initialised to each object during the onCreate, but this means i need to explicitly allow null on each reference. This kind of defeats one of the purposes of using Kotlin. Is there a better solution, to creating instances of UI Objects within my activities in Android.

This is how I am doing it, at this moment.

```
    var messageView: TextView? = null
    var firstNameView: EditText? = null
    var lastNameView: EditText? = null
    var ageView: EditText? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        messageView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message)
        firstNameView = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.firstName)
        lastNameView = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.lastName)
        ageView = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.age)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.showMessage).setOnClickListener(this)
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.update).setOnClickListener(this)
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use Kotlin Android Extensions to eliminate findViewById?

Comment: I'm unaware of the Android Extensions. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining these as `lateinit`, it should get you past the need to have them nullable if you can guarantee that you'll provide values before they are read.

```
lateinit var messageView: TextView
lateinit var firstNameView: EditText
lateinit var lastNameView: EditText
lateinit var ageView: EditText
```

From the [documentation for `lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties):

> Normally, properties declared as having a non-null type must be initialized in the constructor. However, fairly often this is not convenient. For example, properties can be initialized through dependency injection, or in the setup method of a unit test. In this case, you cannot supply a non-null initializer in the constructor, but you still want to avoid null checks when referencing the property inside the body of a class.

Comment: aaaah completely forgot i could lateinit! Thanks for that

Comment: Glad it helped! :)